# Drupal Login using parameters for login and password in url

Tags: drupal

In our application, we would like to make a link to an online help site built using Drupal.

The problem is that this site is password protected. We would like to put the username and password in the url, so that the login is automatically made when the user clicks on the link in our application.

Is it possible and how  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, doing exactly what you want (I think), can be done using the Autologin module for drupal (http://drupal.org/project/autologin), however, it is seriously not recommended for use, since it obviously means people's usernames and passwords are visible in the url, plus in any access logs. The project has therefore been discontinued, not even sure if it would work in the latest version of drupal.

Unfortunately, since drupal's form generation engine has XSS protection, it prevents you posting directly to the login page and hoping for the best.

There are a number of existing Single Sign On (SSO) solutions out there for drupal, although most of them integrate with another existing CMS or similar.

The final option is to roll your own authentication module, which somehow allows you to do this, but it's been a while since I wrote one, so take a look at the existing authentication methods drupal has for ideas.

Answer (score 4):

The current replacement for Autologin is the latest version of [Securesite](http://drupal.org/project/securesite), which is likely what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

External site login

Case on same server and try from any store on same path

like /store

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT','D:/wamp/www/drupal');

require_once '../includes/bootstrap.inc';

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

global $user;

//change this line and put your username and password instead of 'admin' and 'password'

$account = user_authenticate('krishana', 'hiddens');

$user = user_load($account, TRUE);

drupal_session_regenerate();
```